# How can I resize the google map at flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm using an open source for using Google Map API, but I don't know how to resize the map. Here's my code. Please help me.

```
index.html

<body><div>{{sndmap.html}}</div></body>
```

```
main.py

@app.route('/')
def index():

    sndmap = Map(
        identifier="sndmap",
        varname="sndmap",
        lat=37.4419,
        lng=-122.1419,
        markers=[(37.4419, -122.1419), (37.4500, -122.1350), (37.4300, -122.1400, "Hello World")]
    )

    return render_template('index.html', sndmap=sndmap, GOOGLEMAPS_KEY=request.args.get('apikey'))
```

Comment: What happens if you resize the div with a style attribute? `style='width:200px;height:200px'`

Comment: @Frieder It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily include inline styling, but adding a stylesheet is largely considered the most maintainable method.

This is done by giving your desired tag a class. Then linking a css stylesheet to your html and updating the css as needed.

I've included an example.

`projectroot/index.html`

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style/style.css') }}">
</head>
<!-- Other html -->
<body>
    <div class="google-map">
      {{ sndmap.html }}
    </div>
</body>
<!-- Other html -->
</html>
```

`projectroot/static/styles/style.css`

```
/* More css */

.google-map {
   max-width: 500px;
   max-height: 200px;
}

/* More css */
```

This shouldn't be copied verbatim as you'll need to play around with the exact styling to achieve the look you want. The number of customization options through standard css are endless. I'd recommend looking up common patterns and coping what you like.